# How do I un-wiki an answer?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

Alright, I'll admit I stuffed up. I [put up an answer to this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/136795/first-innovation-for-time-traveler-to-low-tech-society) and through some kind of finger-fail, it got listed as a community wiki and I don't know how to undo that.

Is there a way to undo that action without deleting and re-posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular users can't do that, [but mods can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/274942). This restriction might be a relic of the days when a certain number of edits (~20) by a single user would automatically turn the post into a wiki, which would partly discourage bumping just to gain attention. That automatic wiki-ing has since been removed.

In future, of course, just flag the post using the custom flag and tell us that you'd like us to un-wiki it. I've gone ahead and done that here.